# What are some of the best spots in New York City to take really good pictures?

Tags: street-photography, locations

I am not just asking for the best shoots but also where to take the pictures from.

Comment: Is "dslr" really a relevant tag for this post?

Comment: ...also, perhaps this should be community wiki?

Comment: Discussion: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/63/photo-location-tips-on-or-off-topic

Comment: Tagged as subjective since 'best spot' depends highly on what you want to photograph (street/urban/architecture).

Comment: Questions that ask users to create a list of answers (i.e. polls or list-of-X questions), while there not exactly the type of questions this system was designed for, at the very least need to be made community wiki. I converted this question.

Comment: Based on the discussion on meta (link above), I'm voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: Close please for subjective and off-topic as in http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/63/photo-location-tips-on-or-off-topic

Comment: If "subjective" and "off-topic" aren't good enough reasons to close this sort of question, there's also "too localized." It really doesn't get much more localized than this.

Comment: On "too localized" — the New York metro area has almost 19 million people. That's _somewhat_ localized, but _too_ localized should be for things which are really individual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend taking a trip over to Brooklyn via the Brooklyn bridge and going down to the river side. Some classic shots of both the Brooklyn and Manhattan bridge can be got, particularly at sunrise / sunset.

Answer (score 3):

I really enjoyed the city view from the NBC building's observation deck.

Answer (score 1):

Soho, chinatown. Check picaspot.com for more ideas

Answer (score 0):

It's probably rather cliché, but you really can get some amazing photographs just walking around Times Square at night. Also, when I was there a few weeks ago, I noticed that if you go late enough (after 1:30 AM, say), there will still be people present, but the crowd will have thinned quite a bit. Whether this is useful or not depends on just what sort of photos you want, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I think the streets of Soho and Chinatown offer some of the best spots to take pictures in New York. I also agree with the Brooklyn Bridge recommendation. Check picaspot.com for more suggestions